# Unable to read text file in Eclipse using Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, text-files

I am having difficulties making Eclipse (Indigo) IDE access a text file using Ubuntu. I am able to do this using my Windows side of the partition. I want to read off of an external drive. Here is the code that works on the Windows side of the partion:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("E:\\folder\\filename.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but very unlikely, that `"E:\\folder\\filename.txt"` is the correct file name on Ubuntu.  Ubuntu, which is based on Linux, uses forward slashes to delimit directory names, and it doesn't have drive letters like `E:`.  If the file is actually visible from both Windows and Ubuntu, you'll have to figure out the correct path name as seen from Ubuntu; it's going to be `".../folder/filename.txt"`, but you'll have to figure out the `...` part yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be something like /media/drivename/folder/filename.txt.  Try right clicking on a file and selecting "Properties."  From there you can just copy the value in "Location."